# Touch, select, or tap for screentouch devices?

Tags: touch-screen, selection

What is the best equivalent of "select" or "click" on mouse-computer systems for screentouch devices out of touch, select, or tap?

Comment: What do you mean by select?

Comment: I guess you're asking for terminology to use for a descriptive text?

Comment: to use for toggling an option. And by "equivalent of click or select on computer", I think I make myself completely clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap.

It does depend on the context, but if you're describing to a user what to do, the physical action is to tap. Selecting is not an action, it's a function. Touching is technically an action, but in the case of "Tap/Touch the button", tap is more appropriate, though both are perfectly understandable.